# Apart from adding entries via LookUpTableAddEx, , can VBA do more to the lookup table of a non-outline code custom field in MSProject?

Tags: vba, ms-project, lookup-tables

For example, this works:

```
Application.LookUpTableAddEx FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber1, Level:=1, Code:="10", Description:="wow"
```

However, I am searching for a VBA way to edit the entries already in the lookuptable, or even a workaround to delete the lookuptable, then repopulate it with the updated entries. If not, I believe it is possible to edit the outline code lookup tables, but I'm specifically wanting to manipulate the **non**-outline code custom fields.

Below, the second line doesn't overwrite the first line, unfortunately for my purposes.

```
Application.LookUpTableAddEx FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber1, Level:=1, Code:="10", Description:="wow"
```

```
Application.LookUpTableAddEx FieldID:=pjCustomTaskNumber1, Level:=1, Code:="10", Description:="no wow"
```

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate the non-outline code custom fields such as Text1-30, Number1-30, use the methods such as:

- [CustomFieldValueList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.customfieldvaluelist)
- [CustomFieldValueListAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.customfieldvaluelistadd)
- [CustomFieldValueListDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.customfieldvaluelistdelete)
- [CustomFieldValueListGetItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.customfieldvaluelistgetitem)

Also, search SO for [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5Dcustom+field).

Comment: If they are enterprise fields, also see [stackoverflow.com/.../reading-the-list-of-values-of-an-enterprise-custom-field-using-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876419/reading-the-list-of-values-of-an-enterprise-custom-field-using-vba).

Comment: Thanks @RachelHettinger, have figured out how to delete then add (ie change) a lookuptable entry. Curiously my file had an "out-of-place" index number (40, when it was actually 11) but it somehow corrected itself after I restarted MSProject, then I rechecked the index still displayed "40". then VBA threw an error at the line I had Index:=40, rechecked the index again and it displayed "11", then changed the VBA code and it worked (wierd). Now wondering if there is a method to get the index of a lookuptable entry based on it's value.